# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-dom

I am using react with the following packages:

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "h3-js": "^3.7.2",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-leaflet": "3.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My `index.js` looks like the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

My `App.js` is like the following:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import LeafletMap from "./Map";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { resolution: 8, kRing: 0 };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { resolution: 8, kRing: 0 };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <LeafletMap
          resolution={this.state.resolution}
          kRing={this.state.kRing}
        />
        Resolution:
        <input
          type="number"
          min={0}
          max={15}
          onChange={this.onChangeResolution}
          defaultValue={8}
        />
        <br />
        K Rings:
        <input
          type="number"
          min={0}
          max={100}
          onChange={this.onChangeKRings}
          defaultValue={0}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onChangeResolution = (e) => {
    this.setState({ resolution: Number.parseInt(e.target.value) });
  };
  onChangeKRings = (e) => {
    this.setState({ kRing: Number.parseInt(e.target.value) });
  };
}

export default App;
```

When I run my app with `npm run start` I get the following error:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/index.js 5:0-40

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client' in '/home/Desktop/Code/demo_app/src'
```

I reinstalled all packages and its also listed in `npm list`:

```
>  npm list
demo_app@0.1.0 /home/Desktop/Code/demo_app
├── @testing-library/jest-dom@5.16.4
├── @testing-library/react@13.0.1
├── @testing-library/user-event@13.5.0
├── h3-js@3.7.2
├── leaflet@1.7.1
├── react-dom@17.0.1
├── react-leaflet@3.0.2
├── react-scripts@5.0.1
├── react@17.0.1
└── web-vitals@2.1.4
```

Any suggestions why I have problems compiling my application?

Comment: Because that's new in React 18.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am currently using `react 17`, because of the `h3-js`-library, which does not work in `react 18`. How can I still make the app running?

Comment: The `react-dom/client` thing is new in v18. Your `package.json` has you using v17. If you upgrade to v18.0.0, the error should go away. Alternatively, use the older `ReactDOM.render` way that v17 uses.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for your reply. Please add this as an answer. How it should look like using react 17. Thank you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am using `react 17` because of `h3-js` library as it only works with `17` atm.

Comment: Do the opposite of https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html

Comment: @Carol.Kar - I don't think you'll have trouble finding an example if you search for one. :-) Basically: `import ReactDOM from "react-dom";` then instead of doing `createRoot` / `root.render`, you do `ReactDOM.render(JSXHERE, targetElementHere);` E.g.: `ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode><App /></React.StrictMode>, document.getElementById("root"));`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The final solution that worked for me was simply to change the React 18 `index.js` file to the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: In my case, it couldn't resolve  `./reportWebVitals` after pasting in your code.

Comment: Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead.

Comment: Did you try explicitly upgrading react-dom to 18 as well as react? That worked for me.

Answer (score 43):

You still have the older versions of "react" and "react-dom" in your dependencies.
To solve it:

1. delete these two lines:

```
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
```

2. Replace them with:

```
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
```

3. delete the "node_modules" folder
4. do `npm install`
   This should solve your issue and update your app to react18

Comment: This helped me by making me realized I had upgraded react but not react-dom. After running `yarn upgrade react-dom@18.0.0` the path is able to resolve.

Answer (score 24):

You might need to downgrade React and react-dom, here is `index.js`:

###### React 17 example:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const root = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, root);
```

###### React 18 example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: ... or upgrade it

Comment: @Giorgi Digmelashvili Can you please provide answer for React v16.13.1. Your above mentioned solution is not working for me as I have v16 of React. And the restriction is that I can not update the react version as it will change so many things.

Answer (score 22):

In summary, if you are using React 17 (My version was 17.0.2), you index.js will have to be like the following,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

if You are using React 18, your index.js file should looks like the following

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
 <React.StrictMode>
   <App />
 </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I was facing problem, when I downgraded my react 18 project to react 17 project.
i used,

```
npm install react@17 react-dom@17
```

For typescript project,

```
npm install react@17 @types/react@17 react-dom@17 @types/react-dom@17
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok! Firstly this is what I did. I experienced this problem on React ^16.14.0. I removed the 'client' from 'import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client" in my index.js file. I also commented out the

```
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
    root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
    );
```

that was there and used

```
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

instead. Also, commented out

```
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals"; and reportWebVitals();
```

also. After doing this your code should compile successfully.**

Comment: Awesome, this worked.

Guide post: you need not to comment the DOM element and write your own. The exisiting will also work and no need to comment `reportWebVitals`. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

For react version 18.1 (with typescript),
this works for me

```js
    import React from "react";
    import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
    import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
    import App from "./App";
    const root = createRoot(
        document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
    );
    root.render(
       <React.StrictMode>
          <App />
       </React.StrictMode>
    );
    reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Yeah this is work, looks like this is just react 18 way writing the index.js file.. 
But this file will cause error if you are using react 17 project

Answer (score 1):

```
ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. 
Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it’s running React 
17.
LINK :https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot


// Before
import { render } from 'react-dom';
const container = document.getElementById('app');
render(<App tab="home" />, container);

// After
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = createRoot(container); 
root.render(<App tab="home" />);

upgrade react-dom to 18.2.0 using **npm i react-dom@18.2.0**
.
.
.
If this don't work make sure react and react-dom packages should be downloaded 
as same version for ex:   "react": "^18.2.0",
                          "react-dom":"^18.2.0",
                                     or
                          "react": "^17.2.0",
                          "react-dom":"^17.2.0".
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by adding

```
 "noImplicitAny": false
```

on the tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

**A simple solution to fix this would be to first update your react version. Change your index.js for React 18.**

Open your terminal in your project's root directory and run the following command:

> npm install react-dom@latest react@latest

After installed React 18, if you are still facing an error, you will have to change your index.js file to the as mentioned below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Why would be upgrading our react version to 18 ? We want to fix this issue with the current react version. Upgrading to 18 might brings some breaking changes to existing libraries

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the types packages not being upgraded as well. I had to update the @type imports for the new `react` and `react-dom` packages.

```
yarn add @types/react @types/react-dom
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this error when I use [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) to upgrade React version.

Note:

> only modifies package.json file. Run `npm install` to update your installed packages and package-lock.json.

I forget to run `npm install`, the React version is still old (16.14.0).

So, after upgrading the package version using commands like:

```bash
$ ncu -f react -u
```

We still need to run `npm install` to update the installed packages in `node_modules`.

You can use `npm ls react --depth=0` to check the installed React's version