# Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached

Tags: reactjs, watchman

This morning when running `npm start`, I get the error:

```
System limit for number of file watchers reached
```

Because `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` has returned to its initial value (8192)
(How to [Increase max_user_watches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53930305/nodemon-error-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached))

I'm on a new React@17 project with MaterialUI & formik.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72220065/solved-how-to-create-a-new-project-based-on-react17-from-react18/72220615#72220615) show the commands I ran to get started.

By modifying `max_user_watches` to 81920 it's work. However I would like to lower the consumption of my CPU/RAM

**How to tell my project (react VSC) to be less greedy **

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763428/react-native-error-enospc-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was also facing the same problem and tried the following command,

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```