Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client' in typescript
Can we solve this issue without changing the versions in any other way..?
I'm using react 18 but still I'm facing the same issue.
I have tried by updating to 18 in other example it worked but here we're using typescript. Do that really matters like (js or tsx) and this thing here is still pending.

Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71913692/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-react-dom-client
